# How to select the last element of each type with in a list and move it at the end of the list in a sepcific order?

Tags: kotlin, functional-programming

Looking for a functional more concise and optimal way to do achieve the following output.

Input = List of players of different types.
Output = Take the last element of each type and append it to the end of the list.

````
    data class Player(val id: Int, val type: Int)

    val players = listOf<Player>(
        Player(1, 1),
        Player(2, 1),
        Player(3, 2),
        Player(4, 2),
        Player(5, 2),
        Player(6, 2),
        Player(7, 2),
        Player(8, 3),
        Player(9, 3),
        Player(10, 3),
        Player(11, 3),
        Player(12, 3),
        Player(13, 4),
        Player(14, 4),
        Player(15, 4)
    )
    val subs = mutableListOf<Player>()
    subs.add(players.last { it.type == 1 })
    subs.add(players.last { it.type == 2 })
    subs.add(players.last { it.type == 3 })
    subs.add(players.last { it.type == 4 })

    val mainTeamPlayers = players.minus(subs) 
    val finalTeam = mainTeamPlayers + subs
    
    println(finalTeam)
    
}```
````

Comment: If this code works and you want a refactoring, you would need to post it in [codeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Do you care about the order of the non-moved elements? Can their order change, as long as they are before the elements that are moved to the end?

Comment: Yes order matters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if it's much better but I believe you could create the subs list in a more compact way like this:

```
val subs = players.associateBy { it.type }.map { it.value }.sortedBy { it.type }
```

If the `players` list is already guaranteed to be sorted by type, like you have in the example you don't need to add the last `sortedBy`

As noted by @Sweeper you could also get the `finalTeam` in a single line like this:

```
val finalTeam = players.associateBy { it.type }.map { it.value }.sortedBy { it.type }.let { (players - it) + it }
```

Comment: Add `.let { (players - it) + it }` onto the end and that's `finalTeam`!

Comment: @Sweeper yeah you're right :)